# Storing constant data of site/

Tags: python, web-applications, database-design, architecture, flask

I doubt if should use SQL database for storing some kind of information, but i do not want to "hardcode" this information directly to my templates.

For example, now I'm working at my freelancer's personal page. There I want to display information about my status(Busy or free) at any moment of time. Surely, I want to have access to this variable from admin panel.

I don't think that i should store this information in SQL database(Because I will have to add one more table to schema for a single variable).

Key-value storages seem to be good solution, but i will have to write admin panel myself, instead of using admin-generator. Moreover, I will have to add one more dependency to my project, for one single variable.

How do you solve such problems?

Great thanks in advance and good luck.

P.S. I use Python 2.7, Flask microframework, and SQLAlchemy(MySql or PostgreSQL) and [FlaskAdmin](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you will have to persist more details of that kind down the line so it make sense to create generic model/table called eg config or setting for storing things that don't fit anywhere else. Why introduce other storage when you have one in place and use it already - it seems like even bigger overhead

Comment: Yes, I think this could be a good solution. Definitely, there may be a lot of such variables, but they all may have different types. Anyway, thank you very much. I think [hStore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html) type of PostgreSQL can help.